# How to build corretto 17 alpine linux image using docker file

Tags: java, docker, alpine-linux, corretto

I am new to Docker, and I need help to build Corretto 17 Alpine Linux image.
I have an existing Dockerfile which build Java 8 Alpine Linux image as below.

```
FROM alpine:3.17

# install software
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    bash \
    openjdk8-jre
```

How can I add Corretto 17 command to this Dockerfile to run my application on Corretto 17?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an aws [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-17-ug/generic-linux-install.html) to install Amazon Corretto 17 on Alpine Linux

below is the command that neet to insert in your docker file to install corretto 17.

```
FROM alpine:3.17
    RUN apk add --no-cache &&\
            wget -O /etc/apk/keys/amazoncorretto.rsa.pub https://apk.corretto.aws/amazoncorretto.rsa.pub && \
            echo "https://apk.corretto.aws" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
            apk update &&\
            apk add amazon-corretto-17
```

Comment: Or `docker pull amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk` and then `docker run -it amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk /bin/sh` - see [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/amazoncorretto) for more tags. Unless, for some reason, you want _both_ Java 8 and Java 17 in the same Docker image.

Comment: but I guess `docker pull ` command will not work in docker file.

Answer (score 2):

An approach, based on my comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75948555/12567365):

Use the following to use one of the [official](https://hub.docker.com/_/amazoncorretto) Corretto Java images - in this case, using Alpine:

```
docker pull amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk
```

and then

```
docker run -it amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk /bin/sh
```

---

Or, if you want a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk
CMD ["/usr/bin/java", "--version"]
```

If I build the image using this...

```
docker build -t whateveryouwant .
```

...then I can run it with:

```
docker run whateveryouwant
```

And the `run` output is:

```
openjdk 17.0.6 2023-01-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.6.10.1 (build 17.0.6+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.6.10.1 (build 17.0.6+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This obviously doesn't do anything useful, except to show the Java details.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build those images yourself (and you should not!) because Amazon provides several [pre-built images](https://hub.docker.com/_/amazoncorretto) at Docker Hub.

For Java 8 you can choose between JDK (`amazoncorretto:8-alpine-jdk`) and JRE (`amazoncorretto:8-alpine-jre`), for Java 17 Amazon provides the JDK only (`amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk`) but you can find a pre-built JRE at https://hub.docker.com/r/pnavato/amazoncorretto-jre.  In the same page you can find the Dockerfile you have asked for, if you really want to build the image yourself for any reason.